# unable to install package ggplot2

Tags: windows

While I wrote `installed.packages`(`ggplot2`), I will see this error.

> Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

How can I solve this problem?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while installing "forecast" package.

I just ran install.packages("forecast") in RGui by selecting a CRAN mirror. Then it installed all the dependencies and the forecast packages.

Hope it helps you!